# Как "пройтись" по string в C++?

Tags: c++, строки

Вот я создал массив из строк, пишу туда предложение, а потом я должен найти слово в котором 1я и последняя буквы одинаковы, вот код:

```
int main()
{
    string A[100];

    int a=0;
    for (int i=0; i < 100;i++)
    {
        cin >> A[i];
        a++;
        if ((A[i] == ".") || (A[i] == "!") || (A[i]) == "?") { break; }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a;i++)
    {

    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `std::string` имеет методы `back` и `front`, которые возвращают соответственно последний и первый символы строки

Comment: Поскольку в каждом элементе массива у вас одно слово предложения, то очень просто --  последняя буква в слове это `A[i][A[i].size() - 1]` и весь  цикл  `for (int i = 0; i < a;i++) if (A[i][0] == A[i][A[i].size()  - 1]) cout << .....`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++)
    {
       if(a[i][0]==a[i][a[i].length()-1]) cout<<"YES!!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вообще массив? Может, так?..

```
int main()
{
    string A;
    for(;;)
    {
        cin >> A;
        if (A.find_first_of(".?!") != A.npos) break;
        if (A.front() == A.back()) cout << A << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```